# Is there a way to simplify this maven command for sonar?

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I'm running the following sonar command with maven:

```
mvn clean compile sonar:sonar
```

I'd like to just run:

```
mvn sonar:sonar
```

(ie have the sonar task trigger the clean and compile steps)

Is there a way to express this as a dependency in maven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick Answer: No - not by declaring dependencies nor by having the plugin be in charge of the lifecycles and their phases to be run prior to the plugin's goal.

By `mvn clean compile sonar:sonar` you are instructing Maven to first run the entire clean-lifecycle with all its phases - then continoue with the default lifecycle to the phase `compile` and finally to call the goal `sonar` of the plugin `sonar` - i personally think the command is relativly short for what is going on and must not be simplified any further (what would be the actual benefit of a shorter command executing the same phases/ goals in the background?).

You can however bind plugins to certain build phases so that if the phase is run (say the phase `process-classes` right after phase `compile` in the default lifecycle) the plugin's goal will be executed automaticially.

This would abstract the need of explicitly calling `sonar:sonar` and allow for example to just call `mvn clean process-classes` and have `sonar:sonar` beeing executed in the `process-classes` phase of the default lifecycle.

Now to come back to your question one could generally ask if a Maven plugin can take controll of the lifecycles and phases beeing executed prior to its own goal which is as faar as i know not possible with "standard Maven techniques" (I however dont know of the possibilities if you write your own plugin).